# How to change App Name in Google' AdMob

Tags: ios, admob

My app is and iOS app but I have AdMob ads coded in as well. I just changed my iOS app name for the game and I need to change it in AdMob. How do I change my app name in AdMob? I can't seem to find anything that allows me to change the name.

My app isn't in App Store yet. I don't know if this makes a difference of whether I can change App name in AdMob or not.

Comment: Do you mean the campaign name?

Comment: When you're on Admob's home and scroll down to Manage Your App. Under that it says the name of the app. I want to change the name of the app there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution currently available is to `link` to the app in the app store.

Once you publish your app to the app store, just go to your admob console, select the app name and click the link button to link it to the app in the app store. After linking, the name will be automatically updated.

Comment: I was thinking i'd have to do it that way when I search for my app in app store in that link  button that I saw. But thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 1):

1. Under Apps, Click on your app
2. Click on App settings
3. Under App info, you can click on the edit symbol shown to modify your app's name

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[this is how to rename your App in Google AdMob, Firstly you have to click on Apps Setting than click edit icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkTGW.png)